# MIPS opcode in I format for sw

Tags: assembly, format, mips, opcode

How do you find the opcode of the following MIPS instruction?

```
sw $t0, 8($t1)
```

I understand that this instruction is in the 'I' format and requires an opcode of 6 bits, an rs of 5 bits, an rt of 5 bits, and a constant address of 16 bits to form the 32-bit instruction. How do I find the 6 bit opcode? How do . I find the 5 bit rs and rt? It's my knowledge that rs is $t1 and that rt is $t0.

Their respective values are 8 and 9, but I'm a bit lost in terms of the opcode and constant address.

Would appreciate any clarification or tips.

Comment: You look them up in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Comment: I understand I can use a textbook or reference sheet, which I am. My issue is I don't know how to pull the info I need from the data sheet. I understand how to find rs, rt, and rd in many cases, but I'm confused how to figure out what the opcode, shamt, and funct values are.

Comment: `opcode` should be listed in your reference, that defines the instruction to be `sw`. This instruction only has `rs`, `rt` and `offset`, and your reference should show how to put those together. e.g. `1010 11ss ssst tttt oooo oooo oooo oooo`. What trouble do you have exactly?

Comment: I was being asked how to convert the given instruction to a 32-bit binary instruction. I think I'm realizing now how to find the information I need to do this. You're given the opcode in the data sheet, from there you know what format is being used and you can determine values for the registers and such. My issue was how to pull this info from the data sheet to generate the binary instruction but I think I've figured it out now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For example, 
    sw $t0, 8($t1)
has the 'I' format. It requires 6 bits for op, 5 bits for rs, and 5 bits for rt, and 16 bits for the constant address or 'immediate'. The respective values for each are 101011(op: 0x2b), 01000, 01001, and 0000000000000100.

This yields: 10101101000010010000000000000100

Comment: 8 is 1000, not 100.